# How to automatically close DIV when another page is loaded

Tags: html, css, expand

By using the css below, I could make div expanded when a button is clicked.
This DIV is fixed on the top of every page. 
But it always appears in the expanded form even when I move to another page.
How can I automatically close it when other pages are loaded?

```css
#expend {
  display:none;  
}

#expend + .smalldesc {
  max-height:52px;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:all .3s ease;
}

#expend:checked + .smalldesc {
  max-height:250px;  
}

label {
  color:blue;
  text-decoration:underline;
  cursor:pointer;
}

label:hover {
  text-decoration:none;  
}
```

```html
<div class="service-1 click1">
<div class="row">
  <input type="checkbox" id="expend" />
  <div class="medium-12 small-12 columns smalldesc">
  <p class="font16 ">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <label for="expend">Read More</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: set checkbox to `checked=false` when other pages are loaded.

Comment: @Smollet777 How can I set the case "when other pages are loaded"?

Comment: I don't know how you change the page.

Comment: @Smollet777 I'm using Cargocollective. So when a new page's loaded by clicking menu or a thumbnail, the url is extended like "www.lorem.com/ipsum". Sorry... I'm so poor at this kind of CSS and JQuery.

Comment: The div is expanded when `<input type="checkbox" id="expend" />` (which is hidden) is checked. You can see it if you remove `#expend {
  display:none;  
}`

Comment: Ok, what template do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you add this on every page it would set the checkbox to unchecked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#expend').prop('checked', false);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: As I'm using Cargocollective, I cannot control the HTML of every page. So I added the script you gave me on the body HTML control, but it doesn't work.... I think it's because it doesn't refresh the former setting when I move to another page.

Comment: If you test it in the console after clicking "Read More" it should work. It worked for me when using the code you shared.

Comment: After reading the CargoCollective Knowledgebase, it says you have to sign up for the "Site Upgrade" (paid account) to be allowed to add "custom HTML" which includes scripts. I also learned they use jQuery. I've updated my answer to show exactly what to add if you do have a paid version.